# How to capture response time between moving 1 request to another request in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

My scenario is, I am on page 1 and want to move to page 2 on search result page.

I want to Capture response time or the time taken to navigate from 1 page to 2nd page of search result.

How can I achieve it using Jmeter?

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

If "moving" from page 1 to to page 2 generates a [HTTP Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) - the response time for that [HTTP Request sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) would be the time you're looking for. Just make sure that [JMeter is configured to behave like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) in order to get realistic response time.

If "moving" doesn't generate a HTTP Request (i.e. new chunk of results simply becomes visible) - you won't be able to measure this using JMeter built-in components, if you need to measure rendering time you will need to go for a real browser, for example [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) plugin which provides JMeter integration with [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) browser automation framework.